# NSString with \0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

What is the best way to initiate NSString that contains @"\0"?

```
NSString* foo = @"bar\0";
```

causes 'CFString literal contains NUL character' warning.

Comment: A warning doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: @tofutim: While a warning does not necessarily mean that a problem exists, ignoring one or dismissing it because it "doesn't seem so bad" is not an appropriate response at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSString` objects are for text. Consider using an `NSData` or `NSMutableData` object if you wish to have non-text data in amongst textual data (for example, when it is to be written to a socket or saved to a file).

Comment: Yes, I am writing a program to send string through udp. I tried to use NSMutableData and the problem was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* put a NUL character into an `NSString` instance, here's one example:

```
int main() {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello%CWorld!", 0];
    NSData *bytes = [string dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
    NSLog(@"bytes: %@", bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

**Be aware** that at surprising points in your app's execution, the string will be converted into a C string (or something similar) for interacting with lower-level API, and that this will cause the string to be truncated. As an example, the output of the above program is this:

> 2011-06-02 09:18:30.307
>   Untitled[294:707] string: Hello
>
> 2011-06-02 09:18:30.309
>   Untitled[294:707] bytes: <48656c6c
>   6f00576f 726c6421>

Showing that the `NSString` itself is completely intact but that `NSLog()` won't display it correctly.

Comment: thanks - really this answer really helped me. The factor is the "%C" format specifier which enabled me to replace "\000" (which causes a compiler warning) with "%C", 0